# How to upgrade node in codio's terminal?

Tags: node.js, codio

I need node +5, but the current setting is :

```
node --version
# v0.10.25
```

**Is there a way to upgrade node to --version +5 ?**

Answer (score 2):

Answer is on the [Node tutorial page](https://codio.com/docs/ide/tutorials/node/)

nvm install 5.3

You can check the lastest version available on http://nodejs.io , the Codio team follow it reactively.